# Database Question - Transactions

Tags: database

What does it mean for a database to be in an inconsistent state?

I know it is relative to transactions but not entirely sure what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that data is inconsistent, probably because some tables have been updated without updating related tables.

Answer (score 0):

This could potentially mean a few things in general: a corrupt database file (which happens often in Access) or that transactions are still in process or not completed or a file related to the database is in an open state. Once the "work" completes the status should return to "consistent."

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a banking application and you're not using transactions. You intend to transfer money from one account to another, and you first do something like `update balance set value = value + $20 where account = account2`, followed by `update balance set value = value - $20 where account = account1`. Now lets say something bad happens between these queries (server crashes, client submitting the queries crashes, or even another client gets in with queries in the middle and messes things up)... your database has problems.

With transactions, your multiple queries will be atomic. That is.. all or nothing -- until you've committed the full transaction, no other client can see your partial changes and the database will not record one change without the other.

The balance amount is somewhat trivial and contrived, however the same sort of problem can easily happen when adding multiple entries to multiple tables, each of which are intended to be related.

Answer (score 0):

The prototypical situation happens in a transactional enviroment with concurrent processes, and is explained as follows:

- process 1 request data from table A
- process 2 request data from table A
- process 1 updates data in table A
- process 2 uses non-updated data in table A for its elaboration

This introduces inconsistence in the result of process 2.

For example process 2 may try to update data in table A: so the update made by process 1 is lost.

A typical solution to this problem is to introduce a *lock* in table A in the first step, until process 1 ends (either with COMMIT or ROLLBACK), so that other process cannot use the same resource until the lock has released.